# Sending Email using Outlook / Office365 with Laravel - Failed to authenticate on SMTP server

Tags: laravel, email, outlook, office365, tls1.2

I'm trying to send an email with our Laravel app using Office365/Outlook. It has worked well with gmail but when I switched over to Office365, the following error appears:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username
> "xxxxxx@companyname.co" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator
> LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with
> message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
> [HKAPR03CA0035.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com]
> ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
> [HKAPR03CA0035.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com]
> ".

This is what I have in my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx@companyname.co
MAIL_PASSWORD=emailPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_SMTPAuth=true
MAIL_FROM_NAME=CompanyName
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxx@companyname.co
```

**note: this is not the real username, password and from address.*

I also tried changing the port to 25 but I get the same error

I'm using a dedicated support email from my company. And from what I confirmed with our IT, the support email does not have 2 factor authentication and the "Authenticated SMTP" setting is also enabled via the admin panel of Office365 so I don't know what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that for the new tenants, Microsoft turns SMTP authentication off, and it needs to be explicitly enabled. Please see
[Enable or disable authenticated client SMTP submission (SMTP AUTH) in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission)
as well as
[What are security defaults?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I called Microsoft support. They instructed me to change some security properties in Microsoft Azure. [Here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70231003/1462600).

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the 2 factor authentication, the go to your account settings and create an application password. Then you have to use the new application password in your code. Check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Security%20basics,and%20appears%20on%20your%20screen.)